# I'm unable to change the symbol in the grid and to keep on adding the changes to it

Tags: python

I am supposed to show the change in the symbol in the grid according to the coordinates given by coords and the particular colour name - colour_name which is a symbol passed in to set colour function. it needs to save the moves throughout instead a move on a new grid every time. Can I know what I need to do in order to get the expected output

```
from string import ascii_uppercase as letters
class Board():
    points = {'E': '.', 'B': '@', 'W': 'O'}

    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, size=19):
        self.size = size

        assert (self.size > 1 and self.size < 27), "Illegal board size: must be between 2 and 26."  # raising the assertation error if not within the ranges

    # Methods
    #TASK 01-----------------------
    def __str__(self):
        column_names = letters[:self.size] #The alphabetical letter column coordinates
        row_numbers = reversed(range(1, self.size + 1)) #The numerical character row coordinates
        empty_row = ' '.join([self.points.get('E')] * self.size) #the creation of a empty line
        print('   ' + ' '.join(column_names))


        for i in row_numbers:
            arr=print(str(i).rjust(2), empty_row)  #using the rjust to pad strings with space
        return (str(Board))



    def get_size(self):
        return self.size
    #upto this part completely done


    def set_colour(self, coords, colour_name):
        self.coords = coords #takes in the coordinates of the move
        self.colour_name = colour_name #takes in the colour change

        colour_change = self.colour_name  # assigning the colour changed to
        colour__change = "'" + colour_change + "'"  # to make it 'B' or 'W'

        # Assertation errors--------------------------------
        assert (self.colour_name == 'E' or self.colour_name == 'B' or colour_name == 'W'), "invalid colour name"  # assertation error regarding colour name
        assert (len(self.coords) == 2 or len(self.coords) == 3), "invalid coordinates"  # assertation error regarding coordinates

        move = self.coords #takes in the coordinates of the move

        alphabetical_coord = move[0]  # assigning the alphabetical coordinate to a seperate variable

        numerical_coord = move[1:len(move)]  # assigning the numerical coordinate to a seperate variable

        # AssertionError-----------------------------
        assert (int(ord(alphabetical_coord)) > 64 and int(ord(alphabetical_coord)) < 91), "row out of range"
        assert (int(numerical_coord) > 0 and int(numerical_coord) < 27), "column out of range"
        # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        play = True
        while play == True: #While loop for the creation of the board by creating strings of the symbols
            self.move = list(move) #converting the coordinates into a list
            
            for i in self.arr:  # using the loop to create the grid with the numerical characters          
            
             
                self.arr[-int(numerical_coord)][self.column_names.index(alphabetical_coord)] = self.points.get(str(colour_change))    #arr

            return str(Board)

b = Board(9)
print(b)
b = Board(5)
print(b)
print(b.get_size())
b.set_colour("B1", "W")
b.set_colour("C1", "B")
b.set_colour("D1", "B")
```

I'm unable to get the function set colour to work and it doesn't give the required output

```
   A B C D E
 5 . . . . .
 4 . . . . .
 3 . . . . .
 2 . . . . .
 1 . O @ @ .

B
```

in the initial method i did

```
from string import ascii_uppercase as letters
class Board():

#A dictionary created for the colours and the specific symbols
points = {'E': '.', 'B': '@', 'W': 'O'}


#Constructor--------------------------------------
   def __init__(self, size=19,from_strings=str):
    self.size = size
    # self.from_strings=from_strings

    #Assertation error
    assert (self.size > 1 and self.size < 27), "Illegal board size: must be between 2 and 26."  # raising the assertation error if not within the ranges
   def __str__(self):
    from string import ascii_uppercase as letters  # importing the alphabetical letters as uppercase
    a_letters = list(letters[:self.size])  # getting the alphabetical letters based on the number of columns
    num = iter(range(1, (self.size + 1)))  # getting the numrical characters based on the number of rows
    arr = [[self.points.get('E') for i in range(self.size)] for i in
           range(self.size)]  # creating an array of the empyty spots

    # arr = [['.' for i in range(self.size)] for i in range(self.size)]  # creating an array of the empyty spots
    print('  ' + ' '.join(a_letters))  # to adjust the space with the alphabetical letters with the rest of the grid
    for i in arr:  # using the loop to create the grid with the numerical characters
        print(-(next(num) - (self.size + 1)), end=' ')  # to make the numbers descend

        print(' '.join(i))
    return str(Board)


def get_size(self):  # returns the size of the board
    return self.size

def set_colour(self, coords, colour_name):
    self.coords = coords  # takes in the coordinates of the move
    self.colour_name = colour_name  # takes in the colour change

    colour_change = self.colour_name  # assigning the colour changed to
    colour__change = "'" + colour_change + "'"  # to make it 'B' or 'W'
    self.coords = coords #takes in the coordinates
    self.colour_name = colour_name #takes in the colour change

    # Assertation errors--------------------------------
    move = self.coords #takes in the coordinates of the move

    alphabetical_coord = move[0]  # assigning the alphabetical coordinate to a seperate variable

    numerical_coord = move[1:len(move)]  # assigning the numerical coordinate to a seperate variable

    # AssertionError-----------------------------
    assert (int(ord(alphabetical_coord)) > 64 and int(ord(alphabetical_coord)) < 91), "row out of range"
    assert (int(numerical_coord) > 0 and int(numerical_coord) < 27), "column out of range"
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    colour_change = self.colour_name  # assigning the colour changed to
    colour__change = "'" + colour_change + "'" #to make it 'B' or 'W'

    # Draw the grid------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    from string import ascii_uppercase as letters  # importing the alphabetical letters as uppercase
    a_letters = list(letters[:self.size])  # getting the alphabetical letters based on the number of columns
    num = iter(range(1, (self.size + 1)))  # getting the numerical characters based on the number of rows
    arr = [[self.points.get('E') for i in range(self.size)] for i in
          range(self.size)]  # creating an array of the empyty spots
    play = True
    while play == True: #While loop for the creation of the board by creating strings of the symbols
        move = self.coords
        move = list(move) #converting the coordinates into a list
        print('  ' + ' '.join(a_letters))  # to adjust the space with the alphabetical letters with the rest of the grid
        for i in arr:  # using the loop to create the grid with the numerical characters
            print(-(next(num) - (self.size + 1)), end=' ')  # to make the numbers descend
            print(' '.join(i))
          arr[-int(numerical_coord)][a_letters.index(alphabetical_coord)] = self.points.get(str(colour_change))

        return str(Board)
```

The following output comes but it doesn't update on the same board

```
                  A B C D E
                5 . . . . .
                4 . . . . .
                3 . . . . .
                2 . . . . .
                1 . O . . .

                 A B C D E
               5 . . . . .
               4 . . . . .
               3 . . . . .
               2 . . . . .
               1 . . @ . .

                 A B C D E
               5 . . . . .
               4 . . . . .
               3 . . . . .
               2 . . . . .
               1 . . . @ .
```

Can I know what kind of a change I need to do for the modified program to show the output as required and on the same grid instead of separate grids?

Comment: please format your code properly

Comment: okay noted and edited